# How to show lightning toast on top of modal (quick action)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast, lightning-quickaction

I have created lightning quick action to add my component for some functionality.

so from my quick action. When I do some validation like

```
    var opp = component.get("v.objOpportunity");
    if(!opp.Name.length || !opp.CloseDate.length )
    {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "message": 'Opportunity name and close date can not be empty.',
            "type": "Error"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
        return;
    }
```

So the toast message display behind the modal. Please check below screenshot.

Any solution for this issue? I don't want to write custom error message functionality to display to user.

[image]

Comment: hey guys, still no simple workaround except creating custom toast component?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi try lightning:notificationsLibrary

Comment: I used that and it works as in original question :( should I wrap it with div or something ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi I think you used showToast function. I suggest try with showNotice function

Comment: yes, notice works fine.. but from point of view of user experience it is not convenient to show success messages like that :( notice relates to [prompts in SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/prompt/). Doc says `Prompt notice grabs the user’s attention & alerts them of system-related issues/updates.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not an immediate answer, but the long term solution would be to indicate the known issue affects you [Lightning Component force:showToast event displays toast message behind action window in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCRqQAM)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`lightning:notificationsLibrary`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation) and put a notice up over your modal. It's not the same as a toast, but might work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is similar to this.
[Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCRqQAM)

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple custom ToastError component to get around this limitation.

**Usage**

```
<c:ToastError visible="{!v.showError}" contents="{!v.errorMessage}" />
```

Implementation:

**ToastError.cmp**

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="visible" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="contents" type="String" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.visible}">

        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative slds-m-bottom_small">
            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="status">
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-error slds-m-right_small slds-no-flex slds-align-top">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:error" size="small" variant="inverse" />
                </span>
                <div class="slds-notify__content">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">
                        {!v.contents}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-notify__close">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" onclick="{! c.handleCloseClick }" size="small"
                        variant="bare-inverse" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

**ToastErrorController.js**

```
({
    handleCloseClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set("v.visible", false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style element in you component, It worked for me

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .toastContainer {position : fixed !important;}
</aura:html>
```